# Kafka Listner Exception : Commit cannot be completed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

With Manual kafka acknowledgement, while consuming/processing huge amount of messages, we observed the below error.

If we set the max.poll.records property to 1 during consumer creation, will it have performance issues while handling huge load of messages????

```
2019-10-22 23:01:55.208 UTC [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-2-C-1] ERROR c.d.s.s.b.a.kafka.KafkaRxTx - Kafka Listner Exception : Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. -> {}
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:808)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:691)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1377)
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.commitSync(TracingConsumer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.ackImmediate(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:922)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processAck(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:904)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2000(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:384)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ConsumerAcknowledgment.acknowledge(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1593)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will have a significant impact on performance; how much will depend on your situation; you should run tests.

Also, consider increasing `max.poll.interval.ms`.